# Изменение enum в юнити из кода

Tags: c#, enum

Возникла необходимость менять значения в выпадающем списке в инстректоре объекта из скрипта (скачан с ассет стора), сам выпадающий список представляет из себя `enum`.

Как мне изменять значние?

Это скрипт, который я пробовал:

```
public DialogInput script;

public void tumbler_saydialog () {
    switch (script.ClickMode) {
        case script.ClickMode.Disabled: { /*...*/ } break;
        case script.ClickMode.ClickAnywhere: { /*...*/ } break;
    }
}
```

Как мне изменить `ClickMode` из `ClickAnywhere` в `Disabled`?

Comment: эмм... Как бы для этого нужна переменная типа ClickMode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего качать со стороны не требуется.

```
public MyScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public ClickModeEnum DialogInputClickMode;
    private DialogInput _dialogInput ;

    private void Awake() {
        if (_dialogInput != null)
            _dialogInput.ClickMode = DialogInputClickMode;
    }
}
```

Или

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class DialogInput {
    public ClickModeEnum ClickMode;
}
```

И все его публичные и сериализованные поля будут в инспекторе.